# Capture XHR / Ajax requests in Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-options

I am using LogType.WebBrowser, LogLevel.All to capture console output from Chrome's console output window

But for some reason, I am not capturing the XHR messages under the 'Debug' tab

Can anyone tell me why, I can't capture these XHR logs?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture XHR from the HAR using [BrowserMob-Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium)

> BrowserMob Proxy is a simple utility that makes it easy to capture performance data from browsers, typically written using automation toolkits such as Selenium and Watir.

Comment: ah sadly I can't use a proxy / extension of any kind.  I am using selenium grid